# How to create a Fuseki SPARQL server connection in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

How can I create a connection to a Fuseki server through the android studio and upload my owl file into the Fuseki server in order to send SPARQL query and get the result?

I did it from the command-line and it works fine but I need to do it through the android studio.

I found some code but "DatasetAccessor and DatasetAccessorFactory" can not be resolved

```
public static void uploadRDF(File rdf, String serviceURI)
        throws IOException {
    // parse the file
    Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(rdf)) {
        m.read(in, null, "RDF/XML");
    }

    // upload the resulting model
    DatasetAccessor accessor = DatasetAccessorFactory
            .createHTTP(serviceURI);
    accessor.putModel(m);
}
```